# How To Deploy Word 2010 Macros To Others?

Tags: vba, deployment, ms-word

I have a macro that I developed in Word 2010.

How do I send this to others to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the document as .dotm (macro enabled template). Save it to

```
%Appdata%/Microsoft/word/startup
```

Close word. Now, it will be accessible to all other word documents.

If not by default, then go to templates and tick the file saved above

to deploy, create a simple script that copies the file to the appropriate folder. You can probably deploy via email

Comment: This will only work if all "others" use the same computer and same user account as the OP...

Answer (score 14):

From the sublime to the ridiculous, here are four different options:

1. Create an add-in. Distribute and tell others to install it. [Instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597509.aspx)
2. Create a COM add-in. Distribute and tell others to set a reference to it. [Instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa166223%28v=office.10%29.aspx)
3. Export the code module containing your macro to a *.bas file. (Right-click module, Export File...) Distribute and tell others to import it.
4. Copy-paste macro code into an e-mail. Distribute and tell others to paste it into a module.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the VBA Editor.
2. Open the Project Explorer if it is not visible (`View>ProjectExplorer` or `Ctrl+R`).
3. If a new module is needed in the project for your file (`Project ( _your file_ )`),

   - right click on the project and select `Insert>Module`
   - OR select the project, then on the menu, select `Insert>Module`.
4. In the Project Explorer, open **Project ( *your file* )>Modules>Module*X***.
5. Copy your code into this module.
6. Save the file as a `Word Macro-Enabled Document (*.docm)` (`File>Save` or `Ctrl+S`).
7. Distribute the file. The code will now go with it.

Answer (score 0):

I used an old solution - [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) to copy the .dotm file to the `%Appdata%/Microsoft/word/startup` directory. To do this, I set InstallDir in the NSIS script to this:

```
InstallDir "$APPDATA\Microsoft\Word\Startup"
```

NSIS creates a small installer in the form of an EXE file that is easy to distribute and easy for users to install.