# In Word 2010, export multiple VBA modules and user forms at once

Tags: vba

As I have to give up my old laptop and migrate with all my important stuff to a newer and more powerful machine, I now want to transfer all my MS Word (MS Word 2010) macros and user forms to the new machine (also MS Word 2010).

In the VBA editor, there is an option to export individual (!) modules and user forms (--> File --> Export file). But this seems to work only for one item a time. I have dozens of items and want to export all of them at once. Is there a way to do this?

(I have read [How To Deploy Word 2010 Macros To Others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384802/how-to-deploy-word-2010-macros-to-others), but this does not help here.)

Update: My question was based on the assumption that transferring normal.dotm to the new system would not transfer the macros and user forms too. I now see that this assumption was wrong: indeed, transferring normal.dotm to the new system (in Windows 7, this would usually be in c:\users[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates), seems to include VBA modules and user forms. However, there might be situations when one wants to export multiple modules without giving away an entire normal.dotm, e.g. when one wants to provide a friend with some macros etc. So the question is anyway of interest.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Tim, for this links. Usefully, C. Pearson there has published a VBA procedure to export/import all modules of a project. This indeed could be a solution (although a more complicated one than I initially expected)

Comment: Yes it does require a bit of work - if it were Excel you could just use Rob Bovey's Code Cleaner http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: After [How can I create a calendar input in VBA Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel) I have been looking for an inspiration. Thanks for providing one! I am going to work on this and see if I can create something which can work across MS Office (for the moment MS Excel/Word/Powerpoint/Access) to export Form/Modules/Classes from a particluar file to a folder of your choice! 
It would also be amazing if it worked across win and mac and not to mention 32/64 bit Office. So THANK YOU :)